# Azure app service windows container - File share storage mount read/write access

Tags: azure, windows-container, storage-file-share

I am trying to create a file inside of the mounted folder in the Azure app service windows container.

But I get an error as "parameter incorrect".

Once the Azure Fileshare mounted, the running container should have full access?

**Console Error Screenshot:**

[image: Console Error Screenshot]

**Update 1:**

Below is how the storage been mounted.

App service storage mount configuration screenshot:

[image: App service storage mount configuration screen shot]

Comment: Edit your question explaining how you mounted the storage.

Comment: @CSharpRocks updated the details. please check.